# Pivotal to estimate lambda of a exponential

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, estimation, inference, pivot

I am studying interval estimation by the method of pivotal quantities. Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ be a random sample from a p.d.f $f(x;\lambda)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x},  x>0,\lambda >0$.  I have to show that $2\lambda\sum X_i$ is a pivotal for estimating $\lambda$.

Since $X \sim \exp(\lambda),\ \sum X_i\sim {\rm Gamma}(n,\lambda)$, right? So the distribution of $Q= 2\lambda\sum X_i$ is ${\rm Gamma}(n,\lambda)$. **This distribution depends on $\lambda$**. Then how can I show that $2\lambda\sum X_i$ is a pivotal for estimating $\lambda$?

Comment: If X follows Gam(a,b) then 2bX follows chi square with 2a degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 2):

> Since $X~\exp(λ)$, $∑X_i\sim \text{Gamma}(n,λ)$ right?

Yes, that's right (as long as you're using the shape-rate parameterization).

Let's call that $S$ (i.e. $S=∑X_i$).

> so the distribution of $Q=2λ∑X_i$ has $\text{Gamma}(n,λ)$ distribution.

How do you get that? If $S\sim \text{Gamma}(n,λ)$ and $2\lambda S\sim \text{Gamma}(n,λ)\,$, that would imply multiplication by $2\lambda$ had *no impact* on the distribution.

Does that sound right to you? We know the mean and variance of a random variable are both impacted by multiplication by a constant*, so it doesn't sound right to me.

* $E(kX)=kE(X)$ and $\text{Var}(kX) = k^2 \text{Var}(X)$ by elementary properties of expectation and the definition of variance.

Comment: :Then $E(Q)=2$ and $Var(Q)=4$.Then Q~ $Gamma (n,2)$ which does not depend on $\lambda$

Comment: :No it has to be Q~$Gamma (n,1/2)$. But should **n** now be n/2.Then this has a Chi Squared distribution with n degrees of freedom

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to see the result:

you know that 
$P(X_i > x) = e^{-\lambda x}
$
then$$P(2\lambda X_i > x) = P(X_i > x/2\lambda ) = e^{-x/2}
$$
This proves that the distribution of $Q = 2\lambda\sum X_i$ does not depend on $\lambda$.

Now I wonder how you intend to use this quantity to estimate $\lambda$, as this is not a function of the observations only (you multiply  by $\lambda$!).

Comment: Using this pivotal Quantity I have to construct a confidence interval for $\lambda$  .That's why I am interested in Chi Squared distribution.If it make n in $\sum X_i$ distribution to n/2 when it comes to distribution of Q then I can construct the Confidence interval using chi Squared distribution